# Regarding saving image in database in sqlite manager in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application where i have to save image  in database,Can somebody provide me the link of sqlite manager android......

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches, but  [this worked](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database)  for me

Comment: Andro_selva,,,I have sqlite database browser on my system installed.. should i create new entry in the browser or what to do???